# How is it possible to change background color of slide and color of all text in slide?

Tags: beamer, presentations

Using this as a test reproducable example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
 \begin{itemize}
        \item Text:
        \break
        \begin{itemize}
           \item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\textbf{What is lorem ipsum}: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.} \break
            \item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\textbf{why do you use it}:It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).}

        \end{itemize}
        \break
        \end{itemize} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How is it possible to send the background color of slide from white to dark and for the whole text in the slide change the color form black to white and make red the bullet/item list?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to Quickly Change Beamer Colors](https://ramblingacademic.com/2015/12/how-to-quickly-overhaul-beamer-colors/). I personally use the `\setbeamercolor{palette primary/secondary/tertiary/quaternary}{...}` method to set the color palette according to my university’s official colors.

Comment: @RuixiZhang the examples show only some specific parts

Comment: @Stiar Please, if you have questions about beamer documents, tag them with `beamer`

Comment: @Stiar In addition to @samcarter’s answer below, [here is a cheat sheet](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf) for beamer apperance. Please, first take a look at the [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

To answer what you asked in your question: You can change the background and font colour like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Lorem Ipsum 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### [image]

However to make a nice looking presentation, you'll have to adjust the colours of many more things. So instead of fiddling with the colours yourself, use one one the dark colour themes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usecolortheme{owl}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Lorem Ipsum 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If only this could be *easily* done mid document, just for one frame...